# Using association params in collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, delegates

I want to narrow down a collection using params accessible through association

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
load_and_authorize_resource
  def index
    if params[:event_id] then
      @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
      if params[:category_id] then
        @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
        @posts = Post.where(:event_id => @event.id, 
                  :product => {:category_id => @category.id })
      end
    end
  end
```

Gives me the error

```
No attribute named 'category_id' exists for table 'product'
```

But the column 'category_id' does exist in the table 'product'.  Searching for this error hasn't shown me anything helpful yet. I've also tried using 'delegate' to make the attribute accessible but that hasn't worked either.  I'm stumped.

Here is the schema

```
  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.float    "quantity"
    t.datetime "deadline"
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "products", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "desc"
    t.text     "ingredients"
    t.float    "deposit"
    t.float    "cost"
    t.string   "units"
    t.float    "quantity"
    t.float    "deadline_hours"
    t.boolean  "presell_option"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "club_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Edit:

When I correct ':product' to ':products' I get this related error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: products.category_id: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (("products"."category_id" = 2 AND "posts"."event_id" = 10))
```

This puzzles me further, the schema says I do have the category_id in the products table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the attribute name `products` instead of `product`. This is one one Rails exceptions to the rule.

```
@posts = Post.joins(:product).where(:event_id => @event.id, 
                  :products => {:category_id => @category.id })
```

Comment: I tried changing this, see my edit, any ideas on the error?  Is there anything else I need to include?

Comment: Updated my answer take a look.

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you.  I guess I'll have to learn what joins does and where I need to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
    @posts = Post.where(:event_id => @event.id, 
              :products => {:category_id => @category.id })
```

Comment: @thejonster, Are you sure the database is fully migrated? Just confirming.

Comment: Yep, these tables were migrated early on in my project (and I just double checked too), I do try migrate with every change.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your code and make your life easier by using MetaSearch gem. It's very nice tool! Video tutorial: [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch). Documentation: [here](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metasearch/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll be implementing this for search functionality.  My reason for using params here is for seeing posts in certain categories using the url.  Is metasearch a good replacement for nested routes?

Comment: I'm not sure. But I think, in your case MetaSearch it's not the best solution.